# return value in try catch method

Tags: java

```
 public double calRoomCharges(int cusId)


{

    try
    {


        //Get Rates
        String sql="SELECT nights FROM reservation where cus_id ='"+cusId+"'";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        int roomRates = 0;
            if(!rs.next())
            {
                //handle no result
            } 
            else 
            {
                roomRates = rs.getInt("nights") ;

            }
            double tot1 =roomRates;
            String totRoom = String.valueOf(tot1);
            rc.setText(totRoom);

    }
    catch(Exception e){}




 }
```

I want to get totRoom from this method.How should I return it?If I put return statement outside the try catch block it doesn't take the value calculated within the block.

Comment: Aren't you using Java 7+? If yes you should use a try-with-resources statement (both `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` implement `AutoCloseable`); here you do not close any resources... Also, you return a `double` and `totRoom` is a `String`. That won't work... And finally, an empty `catch` block is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: You can declare totRoom variable before the try  set it in the try and then return it after the catch

Comment: I'm just putting it out there that your SQL statement is wide open for SQL Injection...

Comment: How and where are you calculating the total room charge which you want to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.  Let me know if that works.

```
public double calRoomCharges(int cusId)
{
    String totRoom = "";
    double totalCharge = 0.0;

    try
    {
        //Get Rates
        String sql="SELECT nights FROM reservation where cus_id ='"+cusId+"'";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        int roomRates = 0;
            if(!rs.next())
            {
                //handle no result
            } 
            else 
            {
                roomRates = rs.getInt("nights") ;
                totalCharge = roomRates; // calculate total charge
                String totRoom = String.valueOf(totalCharge);
                rc.setText(totRoom);

            }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.prtintln(e.getMessage());
    }

    return totalCharge;
 }
```